# implementation of <*> for Reader

Tags: haskell

Can somebody please explain how to run `getDogR1`. Both `<$>` and `<*>` expect a parameter. However the `Reader` type is not a function and has no parameters. So how do we pass a `Person` data type? For example, it is not possible to run `getDogR1` using `getDogR1 pers` which is how `getDogR` would be run: `getDogR pers`.

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader {runReader :: r -> a}

instance Functor (Reader r) where
  fmap f (Reader f1) = Reader $ f . f1

instance Applicative (Reader r) where
  pure :: a -> Reader r a
  pure a = Reader $ const a
  (<*>) :: Reader r (a -> b) -> Reader r a -> Reader r b
  Reader rab <*> Reader ra = Reader $ \r -> rab r (ra r)
-----------------------------------------------------------------
newtype HumanName = HumanName String deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype DogName = DogName String deriving (Eq, Show)
newtype Address = Address String deriving (Eq, Show)

data Person = Person {
                humanName :: HumanName
              , dogName :: DogName
              , address :: Address
              } deriving (Eq, Show)

data Dog = Dog {
            dogsName :: DogName
          , dogsAddress :: Address
          } deriving (Eq, Show)

pers :: Person
pers = Person (HumanName "Big Bird")
              (DogName "Barkley")
              (Address "Sesame Street")

dDuck :: Person
dDuck = Person (HumanName "Jeff")
               (DogName "Mutley")
               (Address "Some Street")

getDog :: Person -> Dog
getDog p = Dog (dogName p) (address p)

getDogR :: Person -> Dog
getDogR = Dog <$> dogName <*> address

getDogR' :: Person -> Dog
getDogR' = liftA2 Dog dogName address

getDogR1 :: Reader Person Dog
getDogR1 = Dog <$> Reader dogName <*> Reader address
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `runReader`, for instance:

```
runReader getDogR1 pers
```

`Reader` is simply a newtype around functions of type `r -> a` and `runReader` is the name of its (only) field which automatically generates an accessor function for the field with the same name. Using it on a value of type `Reader` extracts the underlying function and then you can proceed as in the `getDogR` case.